# socket emits to different socket than it received from

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

If i do something like

socket.on('herp', function(derp){
  socket.emit('derp', derp);
}

The message goes to a different socket than the one that sent the original message

This is how i intend to pass messages for a javascript multiplayer pig (dice game) tutorial i'm trying to put together

the structure of the app is as follows
pig_server: https://github.com/hayksaakian/pig_server
manages accounts/players and games, rolls dice, relays actions
pig: https://github.com/hayksaakian/pig
manages ui, client side; emits actions

How to recreate problem:
first do
node helloworld.js
to run the server

from two different web browsers open pig/www/index.html (from the client directory)

in each browser: create an account, click ladder, click find game. Once the game shows up on each browser, click on it from the ladder page's list.

in the javascript console:
socket.emit('herp', 'derp');
(do this from both browsers)

two new messages should show up in just one browser

Comment: Post a complete code example, so we can find the issue.

Comment: do you mean i should copy/paste the snippets of code associated with the problem or something else entirely? the full source is available on github.

Comment: He meant a reduced example that is pasteable as part of the question